# XPath select an image by classname

Tags: class, xpath

I have an xml sheet with some data and some images that i want to collect only a part using xslt.

However, there is one image with a particular classname that i would like to collect especially.

For example, the XML says:

```
<img class="itemImage" height="130" src="image.png" width="195"/>
```

How do I get the src attribute of this image by selecting it by classname with XPath?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work : `//img[@class="itemImage"]/@src`

Answer (score 3):

This XPath will return the `src` of the first `img` node which has a `src` and has the specified `class`

```
(//img[@class="itemImage"]/@src)[1]
```

However, if you know anything at all about the structure of the xml, you can and should avoid the use of `//`, which requires the entire document to be scanned.